# How can I find the name of the field store in the DB?

Tags: entities

I have a content type for which I have created my own img using cck like this:

[image]

How can I find the name of the table that stores the img field?

Comment: mention the Drupal version you are using

Comment: you would see a table with the name of the field. something like field_revision_field_image_field

Answer (score 3):

**Drupal 7**

If the name of the image field is "Dark Image", then the table name in database will be `field_data_field_dark_image`

**Drupal 6**

As mentioned in this [page](http://groups.drupal.org/node/14444), table name should be `content_type_YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_NAME`. If the name of the image field is "Dark Image", inside the table you will find a column called `field_dark_image` that stores field data.

Comment: The poster mentions using CCK, which is not available for Drupal 7.  I assume the question refers to Drupal 6.

Comment: If a CCK field in D6 is used in multiple content types, it gets its own table.

Comment: @PatrickKenny The CCK module has a version for Drupal 7. From the screenshot, I take the OP is using Drupal 7. (The used theme seems the Seven theme.)

Answer (score 2):

If indeed this is about D6, you have the following possibilities:

1. This image is only found in one content type:

   a.  Look for a content_type_TYPE, eg, content_type_story, table.

   b.  In there, you will have fields/columns like:

   ```
     i. field_dark_image_fid -- the file id of the image file
    ii. field_dark_image_list -- a boolean used basically to show if the file is there and is listable (eg if it isn't a required field, these columns are still here)
   iii. field_dark_image_data -- a serialized blob of other info about the file, alt, title, height, width etc
   ```
2. The image is found in multiple content types:

   a.  Look for a content_field_FIELDNAME table, eg, content_field_dark_image

   b.  In there, look for similar fields/columns as in 1. above that are linked back to your content type via the nid and vid fields/columns.

In both scenarios, more/major information about your image field is contained in the files table, which is indexed off of the ..._fid field/column above, and there you can find information such as uid, filename, path, mime type, size, creation date etc.